# How to install morse1.0 on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ros, installation, morse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed [MORSE installation](http://www.openrobots.org/morse/doc/stable/user/installation.html).

It says 'morse-1.0 is available on Debian Wheezy/Ubuntu >= 13.04'.

I want to ask how to install morse-1.0 on ubuntu 12.04 64bits,because ROS groovy is only supported by 11.10,12.04,12.10.

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63947/how-to-install-morse1.0-on-ubuntu-12.04?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2013-05-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since it is a MORSE specific question, you may consider joining the MORSE user mailing list (morse-users@laas.fr).

On a personal account, I installed MORSE 0.6 binding with ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 32 bit, but have not tried MORSE 1.0.

**UPDATE-1 (For MORSE 0.6 installation with ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04)** : Please follow the instructions on this link, this works just fine ! http://www.warp1337.com/content/morse-and-ros-detailed-installation-howto-ubuntu-precise

**UPDATE-2** : Have a look here, http://answers.ros.org/question/64032/how-to-install-groovy-on-ubuntu-1304/

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2013-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-05-30**:
How you install morse 0.6 on ubuntu? I'm also using furete,too. I'm curious about how morse1.0 connect with ROS,because ROS groovy couldn't support ubuntu 13.04. Thank you~

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-05-31**:
I can't install libjack-dev in blender installation process. It has libjack0 dependency problem. How to fix it? Thank you~

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-05-31**:
@sam I am not entirely sure ! that installation worked for me ! if you have issues then post it to Florian Lier or to morse-user mailing list.

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-06-01**:
How to post it to Florian Lier ?

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-06-02**:
@sam Florian Lier (flier at techfak dot uni-bielefeld dot de)

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2013-06-07**:
Thank you~ I want to ask if I join the mailing list, how can I reply the thread that I haven't get the mail?